# Monitor a HTTPS site requiring login with Nagios

Tags: monitoring, nagios

I'm trying to figure out how to get Nagios to monitor a few sites that are using HTTPS and require a username/password to log in - I can't figure out how it should be done so I can set a username and password for each host, and then define a service to do the check using those usernames and passwords.

I can write a little perl script that will use wget and return an appropriate exit code, but I can't figure out how to get the username/password/URL to the script when it is called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to do that with the check_http plugin

```
-S - SSL
-a "<username>:<password>" - Auth
```

So your command defination should look something like

```
define command {
    command_name check_https_auth
    command_line $USER1$/check_http -H $ARG1$ -I $IPADDRESS$ -S -a "$ARG2$:$ARG3$"
```

Then in your service definition use

```
check_command check_https_auth!<vhost name>!<username>!<password>
```

Comment: When I add the -S option I get "check_http: Invalid option - SSL is not available"  

openssl is installed.

Comment: You have to install the package "openssl" Then it is working! 
`apt-get install openssl`

Answer (score 0):

Is your site using basic authentication  ?  If not, have a look at the [WebInject](http://www.webinject.org/) plugin - this works with different types of authentication.